# Designing Database Schema for handling color like in email systems

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I just designed the Pm System[a simple rather to say], now i wanted to design a color selector for the system, when viewing all pm's it should be shown with different colors similar to google's approach on gmail. below is my existing database schema

```
**Messages:**

Id:int identity 1,1

Message: nvarchar(500)

From:nvarchar(100)

To:nvarchar(100)

IsDeleted: Bit

IsRead: Bit
```

How can i add a Color field in a way that it does not interfere with existing setup. Ex, color for Read messages, color for Deleted Messages[lol] so that i could show distinction using background color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming (perhaps wrongly) this is being output as HTML.

Databases are for data, the colour of a read message is presentation. Rather then store a colour in the database for every single message, or even once in a table just for that, use HTML to indicate its status.

When you're outputting the message list in HTML add a class that indicates it's status based on the database value:

```
<div id="message" class="read"> ... message details ... </div>
<div id="message" class="deleted"> ... message details ... </div>
```

In your CSS define the style for read, deleted etc however you want:

```
.read { 
    background: #e0e0e0;
} 

.deleted {
    background: #e0e0e0;
    color:      #ccc;
}
```

This keeps your database, your HTML, and your CSS all separate which is the way it should be.

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion, this is how it is setup right now. I just wanted to make the color a choice of the user and to persist it thus this question

Comment: UX wise, letting the user customise is regularly a bad idea. Pick the best colours for these (or if you're not good with colours, get someone else to help you), and give all your users a consistent quality of experience.  That said, if you're intent on customisation then DeveloperX's solution of creating a new table that is linked to the user id is probably the best method.

Comment: you do have a valid point there, but isn't UX all about user interaction. When there is noting to interact how will a  user comeback for more

Comment: UX isn't just about interaction, but the quality of an interface. To give a broad example, MySpace offers a large amount of customisation. Facebook offers little. Facebook is more popular by a large amount.
Just because a user might like to have a bright red background for deleted items doesn't mean it's the best choice, and in these cases you're letting your users degrade the UI and UX, leading them to use the application less, and the end result is the opposite of what you wanted!

Comment: If you are set on customisation, perhaps a selection of well designed themes would present a better option, although as with anything that is quality it will take more time. Of course, it all depends on your audience, and what you're trying to do. If you've got the right reasons, and have done the right research it doesn't hurt to break the rules sometimes :P

Answer (score 0):

if you want each user has his own color schema  you can create a table name usercolor as
userid int
deleteColor varchar(6)
ReadedColor  varchar(6)
blah blah blah

and you can store dat in this table as this

userid  deleteColor ReadedColor
1       e0e0e0     e0e0e1

in user interface create a combobox that fill with this colors and allow user to select his own color then store data in database

every time user loads page read user color data from usercolor table and set related color